# What is the fastest way to minimize a function in python?

Tags: python, scipy

So I have the following problem to minimize. I have a vector `w` that I need to find in order to minimize the following function:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

matrix = np.array([[1.0, 1.5, -2.],
                   [0.5, 3.0, 2.5],
                   [1.0, 0.25, 0.75]])

def fct(x):
    return x.dot(matrix).dot(x)

x0 = np.ones(3) / 3
cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: x.sum() - 1.0})
bnds = [(0, 1)] * 3

w = minimize(fct, x0, method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds, constraints=cons)['x']
```

I chose the `method='SLSQP'` because it seems like it is the only one that allows for `bounds` and `constraints`. My problem is I will have to loop my solution on multiple selections so I am trying to gain some speed here. Is my solution the fastest one using an optimizer or would there be any other faster solutions? Thank you.

Comment: There are certain methods for which supplying the jacobian and hessian dramatically improve performance.  Take a look at the [scipy lectures](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/mathematical_optimization/)

Comment: I tested and added the jacobian (thanks for the link by the way, I didn't know such a thing existed) and I decreased my optimization time by 35%. I will read more to see what I can do to improve. Many thanks

Comment: Post an answer if you get a solution.  I'm curious how it turns out.

Comment: Alright, just did it. I will keep searching to see if I can improve and will edit if needed. Thank you very much for your time, I got a better solution and a greater understanding of optimizations methods.

Comment: Keep in mind, that this problem, for a general possibly indefinite matrix, is (probably) non-convex and every solver within scipy will return some local-optimium (without any idea about the global-optimum). This has also effects on benchmarking different methods as the results may differ. It would change if matrix would be pos-def or neg-dev (then it looks like a convex-optimization problem and there are much faster methods than SLSQP).

Comment: @sascha (1/2) Thank you very much. I encountered a problem when optimizing on a larger matrix. If my matrix contains incredibly small numbers (e-04 to e-08), my optimization doesn't work as the tol criterion of the optimizer is reached fast. To make my optimization work, I would have two options: reduce the tol argument and increase the max iterations. Second solution would be to multiply my matrix by a random number, say 1,000,000, which would leave the optimization problem unchanged. Problem is that both solutions lead to a slower optimization (longer opt time).

Comment: @sascha (2/2) Assuming I am testing for positive definiteness, and that my matrix is always pos-def, would you have any recommendations to increase my optimization speed. However, my optimization method needs to account for boundaries and constraints (as defined in my problem). I tried to search in scipy, and could not figure out. Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Introduction

In general the fastest approach will always be the most tailored to the problem.

As all optimization-algorithms within scipy.minimize are quite general, there will
always be faster methods, gaining performance from special characteristics of your problem.
It will be a trade-off, how much analysis and work is done to gain performance.

It's important to note, that *SLSQP* for example is an algorithm, which is able to
tackle non-convex problems, in which case convergence to some local-optimum is guaranteed
(ignoring numerical-trouble within the implementation; which is always a possible problem).

This power comes with a price: SLSQP will be less fast and less robust compared to algorithms
which are specifically designed for convex problems (and even within convex problems, although
they are all polynomially solvable, there are easier ones as LinearProgramming and harder ones
as SemidefiniteProgramming).

## Problem Analysis

As indicated in the comments above, for some general **indefinite matrix M**, this problem
is **non-convex** (with a high probability; i'm not giving formal proof), which means,
that there is no general feasible approach without further assumptions (ignoring
special analysis as some non-convex problems can be solved globally in polynomial time).

This means:

- every optimization algorithm within scipy, will at most guarantee a local-optimum, which might
  be arbitrarily bad compared to the global-optimum

## Assumption: M is positive-definite / negative-definite

If we assume matrix M is either positive-definite or negative-definite, but not indefinite, this is a convex-optimization problem. As you seem to be interested in this case, here are some remarks and approaches.

This means:

- SLSQP is guaranteed to converge to the global-optimum
- You can use solvers specifically designed for convex optimization problems

  - Commercial solvers: Gurobi, CPLEX, Mosek
  - Open-Source solvers: ECOS, SCS

## Example code using Python + cvxpy + ecos/scs

There is no special convex-optimization solver except for linprog, which is for Linear Programming
and is therefore unable to tackle this problem.

There are other alternatives though, as mentioned above and there are many possible routes to
use them.

Here i will present one of the most simple ones:

- [cvxpy](http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/index.html) is used for model-formulation

  - It will automatically proof that this problem is convex!

    - (Model-building and convexity-inference can be costly)
- [ecos](https://github.com/embotech/ecos)

  - General-purpose solver for many convex optimization problems

    - Based on the Interior-Point-Method
- [scs](https://github.com/cvxgrp/scs)

  - General-purpose solver for many convex optimization problems

    - Based on alternating direction method of multipliers (ADMM)
  - Supports two different approaches to solve linear equations:

    - direct (factorization based)
    - indirect (conjugate-gradient based)

      - GPU support for this one as it's all about matrix-vector products
  - Less accurate solutions in general compared to ECOS, but often much faster

Example code:

- Example using:

  - 1000x1000 matrix
  - Solver:  SCS

    - indirect-mode
    - CPU
    - Multithreaded (automatically if BLAS available)

Code:

```
import time
import numpy as np
from cvxpy import *                 # Convex-Opt

""" Create some random pos-def matrix """
N = 1000
matrix_ = np.random.normal(size=(N,N))
matrix = np.dot(matrix_, matrix_.T)

""" CVXPY-based Convex-Opt """
print('\ncvxpy\n')
x = Variable(N)
constraints = [x >= 0, x <= 1, sum(x) == 1]
objective = Minimize(quad_form(x, matrix))
problem = Problem(objective, constraints)
time_start = time.perf_counter()
problem.solve(solver=SCS, use_indirect=True, verbose=True)  # or: solver=ECOS
time_end = time.perf_counter()
print(problem.value)
print('cvxpy (modelling) + ecos/scs (solving) used (secs): ', time_end - time_start)
```

Example output:

```
cvxpy

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    SCS v1.2.6 - Splitting Conic Solver
    (c) Brendan O'Donoghue, Stanford University, 2012-2016
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Lin-sys: sparse-indirect, nnz in A = 1003002, CG tol ~ 1/iter^(2.00)
eps = 1.00e-03, alpha = 1.50, max_iters = 2500, normalize = 1, scale = 1.00
Variables n = 1001, constraints m = 3003
Cones:  primal zero / dual free vars: 1
    linear vars: 2000
    soc vars: 1002, soc blks: 1
Setup time: 6.76e-02s
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Iter | pri res | dua res | rel gap | pri obj | dua obj | kap/tau | time (s)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     0|      inf       inf      -nan      -inf      -inf       inf  1.32e-01 
   100| 1.54e-02  1.48e-04  7.63e-01 -5.31e+00 -4.28e+01  1.10e-11  1.15e+00 
   200| 1.53e-02  1.10e-04  7.61e-01 -3.87e+00 -3.17e+01  1.08e-11  1.95e+00 
   300| 1.53e-02  7.25e-05  7.55e-01 -2.47e+00 -2.08e+01  1.07e-11  2.79e+00 
   400| 1.53e-02  3.61e-05  7.39e-01 -1.11e+00 -1.03e+01  1.06e-11  3.61e+00 
   500| 7.64e-03  2.55e-04  1.09e-01 -2.01e-01 -6.32e-02  1.05e-11  4.64e+00 
   560| 7.71e-06  4.24e-06  8.61e-04  2.17e-01  2.16e-01  1.05e-11  5.70e+00 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Status: Solved
Timing: Solve time: 5.70e+00s
    Lin-sys: avg # CG iterations: 1.71, avg solve time: 9.98e-03s
    Cones: avg projection time: 3.97e-06s
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error metrics:
dist(s, K) = 5.1560e-16, dist(y, K*) = 0.0000e+00, s'y/|s||y| = 2.4992e-17
|Ax + s - b|_2 / (1 + |b|_2) = 7.7108e-06
|A'y + c|_2 / (1 + |c|_2) = 4.2390e-06
|c'x + b'y| / (1 + |c'x| + |b'y|) = 8.6091e-04
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
c'x = 0.2169, -b'y = 0.2157
============================================================================
0.21689554805292935
cvxpy (modelling) + ecos/scs (solving) used (secs):  7.105745473999832
```

Extra-example: 5000x5000 uses ~ 9 minutes (without tuning params).

Some tiny extra-remarks:

- SCS is faster than ECOS (expected)
- SCS/ECOS both faster than naive (not giving jacobi-matrix) SLSQP (for everything at least every N >= 100); faster = orders of magnitude for big N
- I checked the equivalence of this method compared to SLSQP for small examples

Comment: Pretty useful, thank you very much. I managed to get through the installation of cvxpy and C++. I tested your solution everything seems to work (and fast). I will read more on cvxpy.

Comment: Hi sascha, I have another problem with python optimization. However, I am using python 3.6 so I can't really use cvxpy right? I ran into an issue trying to define the jacobian of my function to optimize. Do you mind giving it a look? Thanks!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43793204/error-message-when-trying-to-minimize-a-function-with-scipy-using-jacobian

Answer (score 3):

Based on pylang comments, I calculated the jacobian of my function which leads to the following function:

```
def fct_deriv(x):
    return 2 * matrix.dot(x)
```

The optimization problem becomes the following

```
minimize(fct, x0, method='SLSQP', jac=fct_deriv, bounds=bnds, constraints=cons)['x']
```

However, that solution does not allow to add the Hessian as the SLSQP method does not allow it. Other optimization methods exist, but SLSQP is the only one accepting bounds and constraints at the same time (which is central to my optimizatio problem).

See below for full code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

matrix = np.array([[1.0, 1.5, -2.],
                   [0.5, 3.0, 2.5],
                   [1.0, 0.25, 0.75]])

def fct(x):
    return x.dot(matrix).dot(x)

def fct_deriv(x):
    return 2 * matrix.dot(x)

x0 = np.ones(3) / 3
cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: x.sum() - 1.0})
bnds = [(0, 1)] * 3

w = minimize(fct, x0, method='SLSQP', jac=fct_deriv, bounds=bnds, constraints=cons)['x']
```

Edited (added the jacobian of the constraint):

```
cons2 = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: x.sum() - 1.0, 'jac': lambda x: np.ones_like(x)})

w = minimize(fct, x0, method='SLSQP', jac=fct_deriv, bounds=bnds, constraints=cons2)['x']
```

Comment: Also take a look at the optimize section of this [scipy tutorial](https://www.tau.ac.il/~kineret/amit/scipy_tutorial/) similar to the [scipy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html)

Comment: @Eric B You can also provide the jacobian of the constraint, in this case, `cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: x.sum() - 1.0, 'jac': lambda x: np.ones_like(x)})`

Comment: Thank you Stelios, I defined my constraints according to your dictionnary and again, I cut my optimization time by about 35%. In total, defining the jacobian of my function and the jacobian of my constraints cut my optimization by more than 50%. Will edit the answer.